# How do I return a sorted struct to my main function?

Tags: c, function, struct, return

**Goal: Sort a Struct of 3 Dice and Return Sorted**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
```

Struct

```
struct RolledDice
{
    int die1 ;
    int die2 ;
    int die3 ;
} dice;
```

Prototype

```
void sort_dice(struct RolledDice dice );
```

Main

```
int main() {
srand ( time(NULL) );

dice.die1 = rand() % 6 + 1 ;
dice.die2 = rand() % 6 + 1 ;
dice.die3 = rand() % 6 + 1 ;

sort_dice(dice);

return 0;
}
```

Sort Dice Function

```
void sort_dice(struct RolledDice dice) {

    printf("Die 1: %d \n", dice.die1);
    printf("Die 2: %d \n", dice.die2);
    printf("Die 3: %d \n\n", dice.die3);

    int tempDie = 0;
```

(There may be a better way to do this......but this is the best I could come up with)

```
    while ( dice.die1 < dice.die2 || dice.die1 < dice.die3 || dice.die2 < dice.die3 )
    {
        if ( dice.die1 < dice.die2 )
         {
         tempDie = dice.die1 ;
         dice.die1 = dice.die2 ;
         dice.die2 = tempDie ;
         }
        if ( dice.die1 < dice.die3 )
         {
         tempDie = dice.die1 ;
         dice.die1 = dice.die3 ;
         dice.die3 = tempDie ;
         }
        if (dice.die2 < dice.die3 )
         {
         tempDie = dice.die2 ;
         dice.die2 = dice.die3 ;
         dice.die3 = tempDie ;
         }
    }

    printf( "Die 1: %d \n", dice.die1 );
    printf( "Die 2: %d \n", dice.die2 );
    printf( "Die 3: %d \n\n", dice.die3 );
}
```

I tried changing the `void` to `int` and `struct` but kept getting errors, or it wouldn't update the `struct` in the `main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sorting a copy of your `dice` structure, which is lost as soon as it goes out of scope when the function returns.

change your function to:

```
struct RolledDice sort_dice(struct RolledDice dice) {
```

and in the end just `return dice`

usage:

```
int main() {
srand ( time(NULL) );

dice.die1 = rand() % 6 + 1 ;
dice.die2 = rand() % 6 + 1 ;
dice.die3 = rand() % 6 + 1 ;

dice = sort_dice(dice);

// print the sorted struct here
printf( "Die 1: %d \n", dice.die1 );
printf( "Die 2: %d \n", dice.die2 );
printf( "Die 3: %d \n\n", dice.die3 );  
return 0;
}
```

Or pass `dice` as a pointer and use `dice->` instead of `dice.` in your function (heavier refactoring but less memory copy and thus more performant)

```
void sort_dice(struct RolledDice *dice) {
...
 dice->die1 = dice->die3 ;
...
```

usage:

```
int main() {
srand ( time(NULL) );

dice.die1 = rand() % 6 + 1 ;
dice.die2 = rand() % 6 + 1 ;
dice.die3 = rand() % 6 + 1 ;

sort_dice(&dice);  // pass as pointer so it can be modified in the function

// print the sorted struct here
printf( "Die 1: %d \n", dice.die1 );
printf( "Die 2: %d \n", dice.die2 );
printf( "Die 3: %d \n\n", dice.die3 );
return 0;
}
```

note: your original code prints the bubble-sorted values correctly *within* your sort routine. I suppose that the problem is that you did not find a way to update it in the caller function (creating a function to just print sorted values is useless)

Comment: I have tried the first option that you suggested, but I still lose the sorted version when I get back to the main. I need to pass these dice to another function to determine a ranking(which requires them to be sorted largest to smallest). It will take me a little longer to try the second version...

Comment: I updated my code to the second version. It works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help. You are amazing:) Also, thank you for making your reply simple enough that I was able to understand it....much appreciated!

Comment: thanks! BTW I just tested the first version and it works but you _really_ have to assign `dice` when calling otherwise it does not work `dice = sort_dice(dice);`. Maybe you overlooked it. Anyway, second version is more effective, so good choice.